# Open Manage Access and Permissions Panels via JavaScript in Modern SharePoint Online

Tags: javascript, spfx, modern-experience, dialog

Is it possible to open the "Manage Access" Panel for a List Item or the advanced "Permissions" Panel to share the site in **modern** SharePoint Online (Modern Page/List etc.) with JS?

I know it can be done with legacy 'sharing.js' and something like `SP.SOD.executeFunc` / `executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` / `EnsureScriptFunc("sharing.js", "DisplaySharingDialog", function () {` but all of this is not available any more in modern Sites (a Communication Site to be precise).

For the permissions Panel I woule like the advanced version from Suite Bar -> Settings Icon -> Site information. Not the "Share site" link on the landing page.

Ideally it is not a solution like "use jQuery to click on the list item 3-dots menu and then on Manage Access" but either to call some new API that is available or somehow include legacy Scripts so that the `SP` namespace and all of the global functions are available. It can be SPFx specifc or pure JS.

[image: Manage Access Dialog for a List Item] [image: Advanced Permissions Dialog to share the Site]

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that is acceptable for my case to one part of the question.
On the landing page of a Comm Site (and other modern pages) there is a global function that can be called to open the advanced permissions panel.

```
_spLaunchSitePermissions()
```

Calling this on list pages or site contents throws a not defined error.
There are some more functions like `_spLaunchSiteSettings()`, `_spLaunchSiteDesignProgress()`, `_spLaunchChangeTheLookPanel()` but nothing so far that can be called to open the Manage Access Panel for a list item.